# yum コマンド実行時にエラー: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64

Tags: centos, yum

環境：
CentOS 7
vagrant + VirtualBox

`yum` コマンドを実行したところ以下のエラーが表示され、失敗してしまいます。(`yum list` も同じエラーで失敗します)
対応方法が分からず、どなたかお分かりになりませんでしょうか？

ネットで調べたところネットワークにエラーがあった場合に同じようなエラーになったという記事を見つけましたが、ping を外部に実行したところ、返ってきました。

最後の１行に
*Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again*
とあり、リポジトリ：epel/x86_64のmetalinkがないと言われているようです。

一応 `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/` には色々ディレクトリがあるのですが、これは関係ないでしょうか？

また、`yum clean all` は成功するのですが、変化ありませんでした。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror

 One of the configured repositories failed (不明),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

直接の原因は分かりませんが、`/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` の metalink 行をコメントアウトして、代わりに baseurl 行をコメントインしたところ `yum` コマンドが使えました。

以下のような感じです。

```bash
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
```

Comment: mirrorsの方は割と頻繁にエラーが返ってくる印象で、ググると同様にコメントアウトする記事が大量に出てきますね。